# get parent's view from a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, parent-child

I have a `FragmentActivity` with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/menulabel"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:hint="@string/search_title_hint" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/spinnersearch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinnersearch" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reset_search" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonnewcat"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttondelcat" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttoneditcat"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonnewtext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttondeltext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <side.menu.scroll.ScrollerLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_content_side_slide_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ab_solid_example"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_tmp_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
                android:src="@drawable/download" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_groud" />

    </side.menu.scroll.ScrollerLinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the ScrollerLinearLayout class is something like this:

```
public class ScrollerLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    // code of the class
}
```

How to access from `ScrollerLinearLayout` to the parent layout to get - for example - the editetxt? `FragmentActivity` and `ScrollerLineraLayout` are in different packages of the same projects.
I tried to use the `getParent()` function in this way within the `ScrollerLinearLayout` but it doesn't work.

```
RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) this.getParent().getParent();
int w = r.findViewById(R.id.editText1).getLayoutParams().width;
```

Someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: @FD_ it is a nullpointerexception on `RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) ((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).getParent();`

Comment: Where in `ScrollerLinearLayout` do you call this code?

Comment: @FD_ in a method `init()`

Comment: Do you add it to a `ViewGroup` before calling `init()` ?

Comment: @FD_ no i didn't..what do you mean "add to a viewgroup"? can you explain me?

Comment: Did you add it to any parent view before?

Comment: @FD_ as you see in the code above. i'm using the ScrollerLinearLayout to implement a slide menu. I want to get the number of pixel of the editText because i want to scroll menu according to the horizontal view's dimension. If editText is declared with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` can i get its width and height?

Answer (score 95):

The `getParent` method returns a `ViewParent`, not a `View`. You need to cast the first call to `getParent()` also:

```
RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) ((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).getParent();
```

As stated in the comments by the OP, this is causing a `NPE`. To debug, split this up into multiple parts:

```
ViewParent parent = this.getParent();
RelativeLayout r;
if (parent == null) {
    Log.d("TEST", "this.getParent() is null");
}
else {
    if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewParent grandparent = ((ViewGroup) parent).getParent();
        if (grandparent == null) {
            Log.d("TEST", "((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).getParent() is null");
        }
        else {
            if (parent instanceof RelativeLayout) {
                r = (RelativeLayout) grandparent;
            }
            else {
                Log.d("TEST", "((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).getParent() is not a RelativeLayout");
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d("TEST", "this.getParent() is not a ViewGroup");
    }
}

//now r is set to the desired RelativeLayout.
```

Comment: i tried to do this but it doesn't work. the error is nullpointexception on `RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) ((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).getParent();` i don't understand what can be...

Comment: @Rajin, I added a section of my post to help you debug this issue.

Comment: i checked the log and i found that `ViewParent parent = this.getParent();` returns null. I have this `public class ScrollerLinearLayout extends LinearLayout { RelativeLayout r; // some code public void init(){ // your code } }` is correct where i call the `getParent()` method?

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to find a `View` from your `Fragment` then try doing it like this:

```
int w = ((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getLayoutParams().width;
```

Comment: the `getActivity()` method is undefined for the type ScrollerLineraLayout which extends LinearLayout class

Answer (score 2):

You can get **ANY** view by using the code below

`view.rootView.findViewById(R.id.*name_of_the_view*)`

*EDIT: This works on Kotlin. In Java, you may need to do something like this=*

`this.getCurrentFocus().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.*name_of_the_view*);`

*I learned getCurrentFocus() function from: [@JFreeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7417104/jfreeman)* 's answer

Answer (score 1):

The `RelativeLayout` (i.e. the `ViewParent`) should have a resource Id defined in the layout file (for example, `android:id=@+id/myParentViewId`). If you don't do that, the call to getId will return null. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759352/android-get-layout-parent-id) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149089/6248208)

The use of *Layout Inspector* tool can be very convenient when you have a complex view or you are using a third party library where you can't add an id to a view

Answer (score 0):

parent as View

```
fun View.printParentSize() {
    log("parentWidth = ${(parent as View).sizeW}")
    log("parentHeight = ${(parent as View).sizeH}")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This also works:

```
this.getCurrentFocus()
```

It gets the view so I can use it.