# Android get layout parent id

Tags: android, layout, parent

I would like to know what is the difference between View and ViewParent ? I am trying to get the Id of the parent of an `ImageView` but this I can't do :

```
myImageView.getParent().getId();
```

So is there another way to get this id ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I would like to know what is the difference between View and ViewParent ?

A `View` is a class and a `ViewParent` is an interface.

Although many of the common layout classes implement the `ViewParent` interface it isn't guaranteed.

The problem you're having is that the `myImageView.getParent()` is returning a `ViewParent` which doesn't directly expose a `getId()` method.

As others have said, casting the `ViewParent` to a `View`  using...

```
((View) myImageView.getParent()).getId();
```

...should work at compile time but be aware of the following...

1. If the parent `View` doesn't implement the `ViewParent` interface then the cast will fail.
2. The parent `View` must have a resource id defined in the layout file as (for example) `android:id=@+id/myParentViewId` or the call to `getId` will return `null`

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast your parent view to a `View`, so you can use `getId()` method, using `((View) myImageView.getParent()).getId()`

Answer (score 1):

Surrounding imageview returns the parent layout id.

```
android:id="@+id/returnid"
```

example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/returnid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <iamageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:background="@drawable/white"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a parent view with no id, but you do have a child with an id, the best option is to use `parent`:

```
val layoutWithId: FrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.withWithId)
val noIdLayout: RelativeLayout = (layoutWithId as FrameLayout).parent as RelativeLayout
```

A proper tool here to identify the view tree is the *Layout Inspector* from AS menu:
**Tools > Layout Inspector**

It will give you a better idea of how your views are display in the tree, then you can easily which one is parent of who